# Postman - changing all occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: javascript, postman

In postman, I want to change all occurrences of a slash to an underscore in my string.

So far I have written a test which parses the JSON response and pushes the string I want into an array, from this point my code looks like below

```
//an example string is below

var string =  "1/7842/0889#001";

// convert / to _
var slash = "/";
var newstring = string.replace (slash, "_");


// This just changes the first occurrence of the slash to an underscore
```

I tried using the `g' modifier and this fails in Postman

```
var newstring = string.replace (/slash/g, "_");
```

I want the string to end up as

`"1_7842_0889#001";`

Comment: Just use `string.replace(/\//g, '_')` and refer the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `/` in your regexp with '\'

```js
//an example string is below
var string =  "1/7842/0889#001";

// convert / to _
var newstring = string.replace (/\//g, "_"); // prints 1_7842_0889#001

console.log(newstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it with forward slash and join them with `_`

```
var string =  "1/7842/0889#001";

var strArray = string.split('/');

var newString = strArray.join("_");
```

Or in one line

```
var newString = string.split('/').join("_");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User regular expression which will help  us to replace the characters globally by adding g
```

All regular expressions will reside inside //
   So for your question the following code will help

Str.replace(/\//, "_")

```
Added \/ just to escape it's value
```